# R separate_wider ignore comma inside quotes

Tags: r, tidyverse, delimiter

I have data that I had to export from Airtable into a CSV file. There are some columns where multiple pieces of information are included, separated by commas. However, in some instances the separate pieces of information also include a comma, so that information is contained within quotes, like this:

```
df <- data.frame(str=c("A,B,C","D,E",'H,"I,J"'))
```

[image: initial df]

I'm trying to separate the pieces, by comma, into separate columns...but for row 3 I need "I, J" to stay together in the 2nd separated column (ideally, I'd like to remove the quotes after the split). However, when I use the following these two pieces are in separate columns:

```
df_splt <- df %>% separate_wider_delim(str, delim = ",", names = c(paste0("str_", seq_len(max(str_count(df$str, ",") + 1)))), too_few="align_start")
```

Yielding:
[image]

I see there is a separate_wider_regex, but I'm unclear how that would work given I have varying numbers of commas within str.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `read.csv()` which will only parse the commas that are not inside quotes, i.e.

```
setNames(read.csv(text = df$str, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
         paste0("str_", seq_len(max(stringr::str_count(df$str, ",") + 1))))

  str_1 str_2 str_3
1     A     B     C
2     D     E      
3     H   I,J
```

Comment: Thanks @Sotos, i can see this works with the example. How do I incorporate this in a situation where the str is 1 column in a data file with lots of other data?  I want to add str_1, str_2 and str_3 to my existing file.

Comment: You mean `cbind.data.frame(df, setNames(read.csv(text = df$str, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
         paste0("str_", seq_len(max(stringr::str_count(df$str, ",") + 1)))))`?

Comment: Yep...that does it (forest for the trees). I was stuck because i had been trying to develop a solution within my tidy pipes.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Interesting...this solution worked fine for the first variable I wanted to handle, but the second column kicked this error:
Error in names(object) <- nm : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Answer (score 1):

I had a follow-up issue that may occur for others...in the read.csv documentation i learned that

"The number of data columns is determined by looking at the first **five** lines of input (or the whole input if it has less than five lines), or from the **length of col.names** if it is specified and is longer.

In several of my fields, there were no commas appearing in the first 5 lines, like this:

```
df <- data.frame(str=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G,H"))
```

So when I used @Sotos solution, I received the error:

```
Error in names(object) <- nm : 'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

To get around, this I had to use the col.names feature with read.csv, as follows:

```
df_sn <- setNames(read.csv(text = df$str, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, col.names=paste0("str_", seq_len(max(str_count(df$str, ',(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)') + 1)))), 
              paste0("str_", seq_len(max(str_count(df$str, ',(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)') + 1))))
```

Maybe that'll help someone with the same issue I had!

Comment: I forgot about the col.names argument. Now you can omit the `setNames()`. Just this `read.csv(text = df$str, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, col.names=paste0("str_", seq_len(max(str_count(df$str, ',(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)') + 1))))` will suffice

Comment: Nice! More concise...much appreciated @Sotos